# Configuration for Carrierwave with Amazon S3, hosted on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I've followed the deployment instructions from Carrierwave with how to deploy on Heroku for a Rails app using Amazon S3:

https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Make-Carrierwave-work-on-Heroku

I've added the extra line to config.ru and created the config/initializers/carrierwave.rb file, but no success.

Below is the carrierwave initializer, with keys redacted.

Is this correctly setup?

What else do I need to do?

Any step-by-step guides to help me implement this?

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
config.fog_credentials = {
:provider               => 'AWS',                        # required
:aws_access_key_id      => REDACTED,                     # required
:aws_secret_access_key  => REDACTED,                     # required
:region                 => 'eu-west-1',                  # optional, defaults to 'us-east-1'
:host                   => 's3.example.com',             # optional, defaults to nil
:endpoint               => 'https://s3.example.com:8080' # optional, defaults to nil
}
config.fog_directory  = 'myawsbucket'                  # required
config.fog_public     = false                                   # optional, defaults to true
config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control'=>'max-age=315576000'}  # optional, defaults to {}
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you generate the uploader file?

`rails generate uploader Avatar`

This will generate a file like this:
app/uploaders/avatar_uploader.rb
    class  AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
     storage :file
    end

More info https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave in the Getting started.

This are my files
config/initializers/carrierwave.rb

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',
    :aws_access_key_id      => 'REDACTED',
    :aws_secret_access_key  => 'REDACTED'
  }
  config.fog_directory  = "myawsbucket"
end
```

app/uploaders/amazon_uploader.rb

```
class AmazonUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  include Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper
  include Sprockets::Helpers::IsolatedHelper

  storage :fog

  include CarrierWave::MimeTypes
  process :set_content_type

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  version :user_thumb do
    process :resize_to_limit => [200, 200]
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end
end
```

I also recommend you this railcasts:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads

http://railscasts.com/episodes/383-uploading-to-amazon-s3