# saving images from third party service to amazon s3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, image, amazon-web-services

I am displaying images from a third party service to the site, here the problem is i have to request the third party for the image url and then display the image url which is very slow.

So i want to store the images which are displayed in my site, to amazon s3 or cloudfront .

I am using ruby on rails version 3.2, is there any gem to download/store images to amazon, or how can i do it.

i tried searching in google but didn't find any article regarding dowloading images to amazon s3 directly

Answer (score 0):

One of the most popular gems to work with images `carrierwave` provides such ability as an option, so you just need to configure it as it's described here https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#changing-the-storage-directory and here http://carrierwave.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/CarrierWave/Storage/S3.html .

One more example with gem Fog and Heroku [Configuration for Carrierwave with Amazon S3, hosted on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17264658/configuration-for-carrierwave-with-amazon-s3-hosted-on-heroku)

Comment: I would like to save images in the background, i do not need a form for saving images

Comment: what form do you mean? I don't see references to a form

Comment: https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#making-uploads-work-across-form-redisplays, i can store image url(third party site url) in db and i want to download images in background like running a cron job or someother